# Scrolling formatted code that extends wider than screen no longer possible on iOS app?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

Since accepting an update of the Stack Exchange iOS App to 1.2.2 last night on my iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1.2, I have been unable to use a press, hold and move of my finger to scroll to the right in order to read any formatted code that is wider than the screen.

This is not an issue when editing, only when viewing.

I am near certain that I could do this prior to the upgrade.

Can anyone confirm that the behaviour did change?

If this works at iOS 8.1 (and just not at iOS 7.1.2) then I can live with it until I upgrade my phone but I am not planning to take my old phone up to iOS 8.x.

Comment: Are you talking about the editing window?  The text is word wrapped (like on the web) so you shouldn't be able to scroll horizontally.  It should all be visible scrolling vertically.

Comment: @BrianNickel "This is not an issue when editing, only when viewing."  The text is not word wrapped so scrolling it vertically is not an option.

Comment: You know I looked at that sentence so many times and I misread it every time.  I'm charging my 7.1 device right now and will verify it.  I can't reproduce on my 8.1 device.  You should also be able to tap the code block to bring it up in a full width, zoomable view.

Comment: @BrianNickel The full width, zoomable view helps to see the code but it does not seem to support selecting text within lines of code for copy/paste.  Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Is there a specific question I can look at?  I just tried on my 4S running 7.1.2 and 1.2.2 and I can both scroll wide code block and select within lines on the popup.

Comment: @BrianNickel This is the one I am using to test at the moment http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139069/converting-csv-to-dbf.  There is Python code below the picture.  I can scroll it horizontally on the browser on my laptop but not in the iOS app on my iPhone 4S.

Comment: I can definitely scroll horizontally on that question.  In the zoom view it looks like you have to zoom in quite a bit in order for intraline selection to work.

Comment: To clarify, in the normal question view are you trying to hold to select and then more your finger to the right edge to scroll and select more from that single line?  I've tried in versions going back to 1.1.0 and have not been able to create that effect.  A simple swipe on the code does trigger scrolling without selection.

Comment: @BrianNickel Hmmmm - I just tried it again and now it seems to be working exactly as you described and as I was expecting it to when I asked the question.  The intraline selection is working too.  I think we should now close this as non-reproducible.  (I did retest this only about an hour ago to still see the symptoms then - but not now).

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks for sticking this one out with me.